# Combine 2 ndarrays into one whose first components are the two initial ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two `ndarrays`, A and B. I want to create an `ndarray`, C, such that `C[0]=A` and `C[1]=B`.

Put differently, if `A.shape` and `B.shape` both give `(a, b)`, I want to create an `ndarray`, C, whose shape is `(2, a, b)`.

Is there a way to construct this? Is there an efficient way to do this for N `ndarrays` with shape `(a, b)` such that the final `ndarray` has shape `(N, a, b)`?

Comment: Just do `np.array([a1, a2, a3, ...])`.  Once you have a list of the arrays you want to join, it's easy to use either `np.array` or `np.stack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

```py
a = np.ones((3, 4))
b = np.zeros((3, 4))
c = np.stack((a, b), axis=0)
c.shape  # (2, 3, 4)
```

Array `c` has the following data:

```py
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: Upon trying it out, I see that a way to do this for N ndarrays is using `np.stack((a_1, .., a_N), axis=0)`. But is there a more efficient way than needing to write all the arrays in this line of code?

Comment: More efficient in what way? You could put all of your arrays in a list and then pass that list to `np.stack`. Does that help? `arrays = [a_1, ..., a_N]; np.stack(arrays)`

Comment: The name of each of my ndarrays is of the form `a_i` and my code needs to be generalizable for any total number of such arrays (depends on the data that will be fed to the program), so I am trying to find a way that doesn't involve me going back to the code and writing explicitly, say, `np.stack((a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4), axis=0)` if I have 4 ndarrays in total.

Comment: You will have to update your question with these specifics, or ask as a new question. What about my suggestion to put the arrays in a list? You can have N arrays in the list, and the position in the list would replace the `a_i` variable name.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying out. I guess i have to find a way to create a loop whose each iteration adds to the list the ndarray a_i. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want without having to specify the `axis` you can use [dstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack) which stacks arrays in sequence depth wise:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.asarray([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

np.dstack((a, b))

array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6]],

       [[3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

Comment: The output would have shape `(a, b, N)`, but OP needs `(N, a, b)`.